# Django template {{ item.get_FOO_display }} using only jinja2 without django

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I use Django. I also use standalone Jinja2 to build email body from django models.

I have model with choice field and I would like to get its display value from the model instance.

In django template, it is easy, for example:

```
{{ form.get_foo_display }}.
```

However, it does not work if is it outside of the django template. My code using jinja2 is:

```
Trip participation:\t{{ item.get_event_trip_display }}
```

where `item` is model instance and `event_trip` is choice field (the `{{ item.event_trip }}` works ok)

However the `get_event_trip_display` is rendered as:

```
Trip participation: <bound method curry.<locals>._curried of <Registration: John Doe>>
```

**Known solutions:**

1. Use `{% if ... %}` block to manually select the choice.
2. Append the instance with new attributes in Python code:

   item.trip_parictipation_display = item.get_trip_participation_display()

**My question:**

Is there simpler way hot to call the function directly in jinja2? (I have a lot of fields like that)

Comment: Have you tried `Trip participation:\t{{ item.get_event_trip_display() }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_event_trip_display` is a method. Django templates automatically call methods, but Jinja2 templates don't. You need to call it explicitly:

```
{{ item.get_event_trip_display() }}
```

Comment: Excellent. It was so simple.